# Azure service fabric Linux missing application name and servicename

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I had created a Service Fabric cluster on windows and deployed a basic service fabric app + web api to the cluster hosted on Windows server. I'm also developing on Windows 10 using Visual studio 2019.

Due to cost issue, my company decided to choose Cluster hosted on a Linux server. So I updated some settings to let .net core app run on Linux (Like removing .Exe from the Service Manifest xml)

Deployed successfully on the Linux machine. However the path of the application is different.

For example on the Windows machine, I can access my app like:

myapp.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com:19081/MyApp/MyApi/api/values

On the Linux machine, the url is:
myapp.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com:19081/api/values

The service app and api name is gone.
I did not change any settings other that those settings to make Dotnet core program to run on Linux.

Did I miss anything?

Comment: Hi kelv. Were you able to get this resolved?

Comment: Nope. I think that linux cluster do not have a built in reverse proxy that's why the URL will not have ApplicationName/ServiceName. I tried with Traefik and also got the same result. Perhaps i'm missing some settings but at this point I don't know and i'm currently going with Windows cluster.